# How to convert LinkedHasMap Values into ArrayList/Array in right order?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm getting `LinkedHashMap grades = courses.get(choise).getGrades();`

I need to save the grades values in an array/arraylist.

I'm able to get values and keys in loop

```
String key = "";
String value = "";
for (Object o : grades.keySet()){
  key = o.toString();
  value = grades.get(o).toString();
}
```

And print it like so

```
System.out.println("Grades: " + value);
```

Example output is

```
Grades:[0, 3, 2, 5, 3]
```

My goal is to have each grade separated in an array/list.

Comment: call `list.add(value)` on the list? or not?

Comment: Note that you don't have to iterate the key set to get the values: you can iterate `grades.entrySet()` if you want both key and value together, or `grades.values()` if you just want the values.

Comment: I'm afraid that since you do state clearly what you mean by "the right order", we can only guess that "the right order" is the insertion order for the entries of the `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about the order. Whether you obtain the `values()` or `keySet()` or `entrySet()` from the `LinkedHashMap`, the iteration order of any of them would be according to the insertion order into the `LinkedHashMap`.

Putting the values in a `List` is as simple as:

```
List<SomeType> grades = new ArrayList<>(grades.values());
```

Of course, for that to work you have to change `LinkedHashMap grades` to `LinkedHashMap grades<KeyType,SomeType>`.

Comment: My original map is in Course class, and it's `private LinkedHashMap<Student, ArrayList<Integer>> grades;` It's to store student grades, so it contains Student object and grades as ArrayList, that he have.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to sort out, is the raw type:

```
LinkedHashMap grades = courses.get(choise).getGrades();
```

You need the generic type on the variable type, even if you just use `?`:

```
LinkedHashMap<?, ?> grades = courses.get(choise).getGrades();
```

but if you know a more specific type than `?`, you can use that - it looks from the question like your keys at least are Strings.

Then:

```
List<String> list = 
    grades.values().stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If my edit did conflict with your intents then I am very sorry and feel free to revert it, but it just sounded very weird for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution from a website.

The below codes does the trick if provided that `grades` is a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`.

```
String[] arrayGrades = grades.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

*The code was tested wthin `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` environment.*